# requesting url shows invalid api

Tags: node.js, api, request

while requesting the data by using the request package to get the weather for a particular city its encounters the error.

```
const request = require('request');

       const  apiKey = 'forexample9288d54cbe15a1c55013dd554f98453b';
       let city = 'e.g:Sydney';
       let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid={apiKey}`


       request(url, function( error, Response, body){
        if(error){
          console.log('error:',error);
          }else{
          console.log('body:',body);
          }
          });
```

> error shows:body: {"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key

. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info.

Comment: is your API key valid?

Comment: @SureshMangs its valid only, i checked couple of times its correct only

Comment: Try to run the URL on the browser and check whether you are able to get the data

Comment: missed $ symbol http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${apiKey} to get key value/pairs thanks for your valuable time now its working.

Comment: yeah, that's great